# ExtentReports: Not printing soap request in log.info message

Tags: html, xml, soap, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I want to print soap request in log.info message using Extent Reports but I am getting blank displayed in html report.

```
String str = domparser(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Requests/soapRequest.xml");
        System.out.println("str"+str);
extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO,str);
```

**Report -**

[image]

Update: I added textview but the text area is still of the standard size.
Is there any option to resize the textview area as per the content?

Here's the code I added:

```
logger.log(Status.FAIL, " <textarea style='overflow:hidden;resize:none;'>"+ 
response+"</textarea>");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping up the request/response XML in a text area tag.

```
    extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO,"<textarea>" + str + "</textarea>");
```